# Qt Creator 4.0.2 and Beaglebone Black with Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: c++, linux, qt, beagleboneblack

I have acquired a Beaglebone Black with a 7" display.

The BeagleBone is running a Ubuntu 16.04.3 distribution with no desktop. Kernel 4.14.11-ti-r22

I'm trying to set up Qt Creator 4.0.2 so that I can compile and deploy from my desktop to the BBB.
My desktop is Ubuntu 16.04.3 64bit, running in VM on a win7

I have found a lot of different guides, but they seem to be quite specific as to the hardware they a running and the distribution on the target.
I have failed to find a generic overview as to what needs to be installed. Both on the desktop and on the target.

On the desktop I have installed Qt 5.7.0 GCC 64 bit, GCC 5 (C++, arm 32 bit) and GCC 5 (C, arm 32 bit), GBD multiarch and Cmake 3.10.2.
As far as I can see, this should be sufficient, but when I try and set up a kit I still get the fault:

> The compiler "GCC (C++, arm 32bit in usr/bin)"-linux-genericf-32bit) cannot produce code for the Qt version "Qt 5.7.0 GCC 64bit" (x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit).

And the warning:

> Cmake configuration has a path to a C++ compiler set, that does not match up with the compiler path configured in the tool chain of the kit.

I don't have anything installed on the BeagleBone.
As it comes with kernel drivers for the display and touch screen.

Is there any one of you guys that can guide me to where I can find a list of the the necessary packages, what they do and in witch order I should install them.

I have read a lot of the Qt documentation but at this stage I'm afraid it is only adding to the confusion instead of providing clarity.

Answer (score 1):

From your post it's not clear whether you want to run Qt on your BeagleBone or not. Given the message I would say that you are trying to do exactly that.

If that's the case you will need to cross-compile Qt for your target architecture using the `gcc-linux-genericf-32bit` ARM compiler you have. Cross-compiling for such complex tasks often requires specifying the `rootfs` where the libs and headers for the target system can be found, since Qt isn't exactly without any dependencies. This allows the cross-compilation process to retrieve dependencies for the target and do it's thing properly in order to produce the correct binaries. These can then be deployed (you can use remote deployment and even debug using `gdbserver` on your BeagleBone through Qt Creator using either `qmake` or `cmake`).

Comment: I'm sorry that I was unclear.
I'm running QT creator on my desktop. But I'm unable to compile and deploy to my Beaglebone. probably because I have the wrong packages installed or some missing entirely.

Comment: I know you are running Qt Creator on your desktop. But you are trying to create a binary using an ARM compiler and want to link against a desktop 64bit version of Qt.

Comment: Yes, and I have installed QT 5.7.0 GCC 64bit on my desktop.

But for some reason I get the fault and warnings described in my original post when I create the Beaglebone kit. And for this reason I'm not able to compile my code.

Comment: `I have installed QT 5.7.0 GCC 64bit on my desktop`. Just as I've alreay mentioned this is only useful if you are compiling for your desktop. You **need to** create a completely different kit with a Qt and a compiler specific to your BeagleBone. Cross-compile Qt for the BeagleBone and add it to your Qt Creator.